# Excel date formuale to add in sequence

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am not understanding how to add date sequence in excel as mentioned below.[image]

Excel date formuala to add in sequence:

25-Feb
25-Feb
26-Feb
26-Feb
27-Feb
27-Feb
28-Feb
28-Feb
01-Mar
01-Mar

Comment: One option could be `=ROUNDDOWN(SEQUENCE(10,,DATE(2023,2,25),0,5),0)`

Comment: If you're only interested in the textual form of the date you can skip the `ROUNDDOWN` formula in @JvdV 's answer. I.e. `=SEQUENCE(10,1,DATE(2023,2,25), 0.5)` or `=SEQUENCE(10,1,"25-feb", 0.5)` (don't forget to change cell format to Date)

Comment: @Vivek just know there is a typo. Should be `0.5` as step.

Comment: Non MS365 Version -- `=INT((ROW()-2)/2)+"2/25/2023"` assuming you are entering in cell `A2` onwards